# How to preserve multiple values in multiple rows when joining?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I apologize for the title, but I genuinely could not think up a clearer one.

Say that I have a table of books:

```
id | title
---|------------
1  | Childhood's End
2  | Annihilation
3  | The Light of Other Days
```

and a table that tracks files associated with each book, because an ebook can exist in many formats:

```
id | format | book_id | size
---|--------|---------|---------
1  | EPUB   | 1       | 207 KB
2  | PDF    | 1       | 409 KB
3  | MOBI   | 1       | 310 KB
4  | EPUB   | 2       | 773 KB
5  | MOBI   | 3       | 1020 KB
```

What I'd like to do is issue one select query that returns a list of books, a list of the formats that book is available in, and the size of each format. To illustrate, if I were turning the result into JSON my goal would be

```
[
    {
        "title": "Childhood's End",
        "formats": [
            { "format": "EPUB", "size": "207 KB" },
            { "format": "PDF",  "size": "409 KB" },
            { "format": "MOBI", "size": "310 KB" }]
    }
]
```

I know I can use `group_concat` to associate multiple rows from a joined table with one row in the 'initial' table, so that book_id 1 could have a field with `"EPUB,PDF,MOBI"` in the result, just a comma-separated string. What I don't know is if I can, and if so how I would, select *two* values when doing that, and keep them associated.

Is it possible to retrieve all this information with a single SQL query? Would it require using select sub-queries and if so would that be incredibly inefficient?

I'm asking about SQL in general, but SQLite if specific systems matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `group_concat()`:

```
select b.id, b.title, group_concat(f.format || '-' || f.size, ',') as formatsizes
from books b join
     files f
     on f.book_id = b.id
group by b.id, b.title;
```

This is obviously not producing JSON, so the separators are ad hoc.

Comment: Thank you for this, I wasn't aware `group_concat()` could work that way and it's exactly what solves it.